# punto más dos decimales en evento keypress c#

Tags: c#

Quiero que en el evento keypress de mi textbox me deje unicamente digitar

decimales de la forma ###**.##**

pero solo lo hace de la forma  ###.

```
    public void decimales(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (textBox.Text.Contains("."))
                {
                    if (textBox.Text.Split('.').Length < 2)
                    {
                        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) == false)
                            e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    else
                        e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
//lo mando a llamar así
    private void txtSalario_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        decimales(sender as TextBox, e);
    }
```

Comment: Hay alguna razón por la que lo quieras hacer desde el código? Podrías utilizar un maskedTextbox y en Mask le das formato ###.##

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar algo como esto para siempre obtener solo dos decimales

```
 double number = 10.00;
 string SNumber = number.ToString(".##0"); //nos aseguramos de siempre agregar el 3er decimal "0"
 SNumber= SNumber.Remove(SNumber.Length-1,1); // eliminamos el ultimo caracter (el 0 que sobra)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una expresión regular para validar el formato de tu entrada, yo la colocaría después del if que verifica que exista el punto:

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains("."))
{
    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d{3}+.\d{1,2}$");
    if (regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text) 
    {
        // Si cumple con ###.##
    }
    else
    {
        // No cumple
    }
}
```

El número entre las llaves indica el número de dígitos que quieres utilizar, eg. *{3}* significa que tienen que ser 3 dígitos obligatoriamente. Si necesitases especificar un rango de mínimos / máximos, puedes usarlo como *{1,2} que significa de uno a dos dígitos, para este caso.

Puedes jugar más con las regex, en páginas como esta: [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/)